# std::find wont work with std::string

Tags: c++, string, find, c++17

I've got quite the strange problem. I'm trying to use  [`std::find`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/find) width [`std::string`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string) but I get the following error when compiling in Visual Studio 2017:

```
Error C2446: '==': no conversion from 'const char *' to 'int'
c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio\2017\enterprise\vc\tools\msvc\14.12.25827\include\xutility:3481
```

The code generating the issue:

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <string>

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    std::string s("Just a test string");
    auto itr = std::find(s.begin(), s.end(), "t");
}
```

Replacing `"t"` with `std::string("t")` generates the following error:

```
Error C2678: binary '==': no operator found which takes a left-hand operand of type 'char' (or there is no acceptable conversion) 
c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio\2017\enterprise\vc\tools\msvc\14.12.25827\include\xutility:3481
```

Comment: a string is an array of characters, not an array of strings

Comment: You mean that I have to supply a char array instead of a const char* or std::string?

Comment: what I mean is that you should read the docs ;). Look [here](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/find) for `std::string::find` that also allows to find a string within a string. Note that this is different from [`std::find`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/find) which allows only to find a single element in a container

Comment: The third argument to ``std::find<std::string>`` is a ``char``, not a ``char*`` or a ``std::string``.

Comment: I think, technically, you could also do `std::find(s.begin(), s.end(), 't')` with single quotes around the `t` for char, because the iterator of a string gives you chars, not strings.

Comment: I'll use `std::string::find` then, I'd hoped to get an iterator instead of an offset, but that should be easily worked around tho

Comment: @feareoc -- *I've got quite the strange problem* -- I wish posters wouldn't start off their posts with this phrase.  Your problem is *not* strange -- a container of type `T` requires you to search for `T`.  Since a `std::string` contans type `char`, you specify a `char`.  A quoted string-literal is not a `char`.

Comment: Aha true, I'll have that in mind for the next time. I should have given it a bit more thought, but you've got to realise that not everybody knows everything from the beginning. :) Put yourself in my situation, I've got an error, from a template, which doesn't exactly provide the best error message for me to comprehend and do something about. I thought std::find would work like std::string::find, but returning an iterator instead of an offset.

Comment: Also see [`std::search`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/search)

Comment: Thanks, might use that instead of `std::string::find` to avoid the conversion from offset to iterator

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Since [`std::find`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/find) expects the value type of [`std::string`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string) (`std::string::value_type`), you can only pass a `char` to it (`char`s are delimited by single, not double quotes). If you want to find a string inside a `std::string`, use [`std::string::find`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/find)